# Alert ID name of current element

Tags: jquery

I'm using following code to alert id name of current element.

```
<button id="first">click first</button>
<button id="second">click second</button>
```

jquery:

```
$(function() {
            $('button').live('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var idname= $('button').attr('id');
                alert (idname);

            });
         });
```

but it alerts same = > first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the `id` of the current clicked element, rather than on `$('button')`

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'button', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var idname= $(this).attr('id'); //Here: $('button') should be $(this)
        alert (idname);

    });
 });
```

I dont know what version of jQuery you are using, but [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated as of v 1.7, and removed in version 1.9. 
Use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.